# How do I get access to a .txt file, read and write, in lua

Tags: lua

I think the tile explains it self how do I access these files and read and write them?
this is what my code looks like

```
local openFile = assert(io.open(wasd_ ,"r"))  -- wasd_ is the .txt file I want to open
  local t = openFile:read("r") -- read the file
```

I'm not sure if in the 1st line of code if I shut replace "wasd_" with "wasd_.txt" or the file path (i.e replace wasd_ with something like this --> C:/users/stuff/blah/thing/wasd_)
ant help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:

```
local Filename    = "wasd_.txt"
local File        = io.open(Filename, "r")
local FileContent = File:read("*all")

File:close()
```

The file will be open according to the current directory `%CD%`. If your current directory is `C:\test\`, then the open file will be `C:\test\wasd_.txt`. If you want to find another file, you could specify the full path `C:\users\stuff\blah\thing\wasd_.txt`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it all-at-once if you want; Lua allows that, but you have more control over editing when you do it line-at-a-time; in case you need to use certain edits on certain lines.  It's also *much safer* to write to a new file, so you still have your original, to compare and try again, if need be.

**line by line, keeping original, writing to new text**

```
local path = 'C:/users/stuff/blah/thing/wasd_.txt'  -- wasd_ is the .txt file I want to open
local newpath = path :sub( 1, -5 ) ..'new.txt'  --  C:/users/stuff/blah/thing/wasd_new.txt

local iput = assert( io.input( path ) )
local oput = assert( io.output( newpath ) )

local linenum = 0  --  used as a counter
while true do
    linenum = linenum +1
    local line = iput :read()
    if line == nil then break end  --  break out of loop if there's nothing else to read

    local newline, _ = line :gsub( 'this', 'that' )  --  do your changes here
    if linenum == 1 then newline = 'HEADER: ' ..newline end  -- example of specific line edit

    oput :write( linenum ..'  ' ..newline ..'\n' )  --  read() line strips newline char, so add it back
end

iput :close()
oput :close()
```

You can take out all instances of `linenum` if it's not needed, but I would strongly recommend that you use two separate read & write files, at least until you're comfortable it's doing exactly what you want, and has no errors.